# apache ambari local repository cloudera

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, cloudera, ambari

i have a production cluster using ambari from hortonworks. Now cloudera has blocked every access to hdp repository, because a paid support license is needed.

This hit us really hard because we have big infrastructure using ambari, kafka, ans storm.
I'm trying to build ambari from source but i think that a local hdp repository is needed.

Anyone know how to build a repo strarting from kafka and storm source?

Comment: You could use Apache BigTop's repo instead... But please limit your posts to a single question. That being said, what difficulties are you having reading the README for either project about building the sources?

Comment: The problem is not the building istruction, but how to create an ambari stack repository.
I have installed ambari through the bigtop repo buit seem that big top doesn't have apache storm, and stack repository is ony for redhat, not debian

Comment: Okay, so again, what issues are you having building Storm from the source?

Comment: i have no issue in building storm from source. The issue is that also having the .deb installer of storm, a stack repository for ambari is needed. The ambari repository not only contains the .deb installer but other many configurations for every service.

Is possible the only one stack repository for ambari is the cloudera version? Ambari itself is useless without a cloudera subscription?

Comment: A Stack is not a requirement for a DEB file. You can `dpkg -i file.deb` on the node itself. Anyway, Ambari is open source, and you can create your own stacks, and you don't need really Cloudera, but they are a public software company that wants/needs money. If you'd like to edit your question with your attempt at trying to do that, then go ahead. I will say, that personally, I find myself more-often using config management tools (Puppet/Ansible) rather than Ambari for service installation/monitoring of Hadoop clusters because Ambari has always been terrible at managing larger clusters